# upload whole folder to s3 using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi i am trying to move all folders from my local machine to S3 bucket,
but seem S3 only move files and create folder in S3, leave folder empty in my local machine, so how can move whole folder to S3 or clean my local folder after uploading, command i was using it

```
aws s3 mv . s3://bucketname/Upload/ --recursive
```

Comment: Just delete the local directory after the `aws s3 mv`. After all, it's just doing a Copy & Delete, so you can delete the folder after the files have been moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who comment or answer, i fix issue with creating power shell script delete any empty folder after move files

```
Set-Location -Path C:\upload-PassThru
Invoke-Expression "aws s3 mv . s3://bucket_name --recursive"
$rootPath = "C:\upload\"
foreach($childItem in (Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse))
{
    # if it's a folder AND does not have child items of its own
    if( ($childItem.PSIsContainer) -and (!(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $childItem.FullName)))
    {
        # Delete it
        Remove-Item $childItem.FullName -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```